# can powerbi support and display images using binary?

Tags: image, powerbi, binary-data

I use a query from SQL to generate a report, and i have a column that is var binary for images.

Using GetData i pull this into PowerBI,

How do i then get the images generated ?

I can view the column containing the binary code in the query editor in PowerBI

Column name :Image

[image]

However it is not available outside of the query editor

[image]

Is there some setting i need to enable to get this to work, or is it even possible ?

Below is the query i use to pull the data:

```
Select 
    prd.ShortCode                                       As 'Short Code'
,   st.CountryName                                      As 'Country'
,   st.Concept                                          As 'Partner'
,   prd.StyleDescription                                As 'Product Description'
,   prd.StockHoldingGroup                               As 'Stock Holding Group'
,   dept.DepartmentNumber                               As 'Department'
,   Sum(sls.SalesExVAT/sls.ExchangeRateEuro)            As 'Sales Ex VAT'
,   Sum(sls.SalesQuantity)                              As 'Sales Quantity'
,   Count(Distinct(sls.BranchNo))                       As 'No of Stores Sold'
,   img.SmallImage                                      As 'Image'


From
    euuksql01.dashboard.dbo.Calendar                cal

Inner Join
    euuksql01.dashboard.dbo.Sale                    sls
On  sls.DateID = cal.DateID

Inner Join
    euuksql01.dashboard.dbo.Product                 prd
On  prd.ProductID = sls.ProductID

Inner Join
    euuksql01.dashboard.dbo.Department              dept
On  dept.DeptID = prd.DepartmentID

Inner Join
    euuksql01.dashboard.dbo.DistrictStructure       st
On  sls.BranchNo = st.BranchNo

Inner Join
    euuksql01.dashboard.dbo.ProductImage                                img
On  img.ShortCode = prd.ShortCode

Where
    cal.FiscalYearWeek      = (Select FiscalYearWeek From euuksql01.dashboard.dbo.calendar where convert(date,getdate()-7) = FullDate)
And st.StoreType            = 'Concession'
And prd.StockHoldingGroup   Not In ('0441','0444','0445')
And dept.DepartmentNumber   Not In (31,32,50,51,52,53,54,55)

Group By
    prd.ShortCode
,   st.CountryName
,   st.Concept
,   prd.StyleDescription
,   prd.StockHoldingGroup
,   dept.DepartmentNumber
,   img.SmallImage
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Power BI does not support displaying binary data as image.

It only supports displaying [image from URL](http://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Getting-Image-URLs-to-display-Image/td-p/216843) / [inserting image](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/guided-learning/powerbi-learning-3-10-create-shapes-images/) at the moment.

You can find the relevant idea suggestion [here](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/7340150-data-model-image-binary-support-in-reports). (with a lot of spam comments because of the word `binary`..)

Comment: i was really hoping that this was NOT the answer thanks for confirming, hopefully this is something they put in an upgrade